# jquery datapicker in rails default value

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, datepicker

I need to give a default value in input 'date' value if exist or Time.now if not.

```
<div class="input-append date" id="datepicker" data-date="Time.now" data-date-     format="dd-mm-yyyy">
    <input size="16" type="text" value="" name="date">
    <input type="submit" style="display:none;" id="submit">
    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
  </div>
```

my js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#datepicker").change(function(){
        $("#submit").click();
    });
    $('#datepicker').datepicker();
});
```

Anybody can help?

Comment: What is the name of the file where your javascript is located? I mean, is it js.coffee, js, js.erb or...?

Comment: my file is application.js

Answer (score 0):

If your model is required to have a default value for this date attribute all the time, and not just in this js datepicker, then I'd suggest a better solution is to override the getter method for the attribute.

Assuming your attribute was named `start_date`, and you want your default to be `Time.now`, then something like this would suffice:

```
class SomeModel
  def start_date
    read_attribute(:start_date) || Time.now
  end
end
```

Of course, if you want to only provide a default for the JS in the views in a particular controller, you could also just set a default in the controller before passing the data to the view:

```
class SomeModelController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @some_model = SomeModel.find(params[:id])
    @some_model.start_date ||= Time.now
  end
end
```

However, if you *REALLY* want to just provide a default to the JS, try something like this in your JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#datepicker').datepicker("setDate": new Date());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this, in order not to take initialization out of assets, you just provide a value on ready. Let's suppose you send or not a `@defaultdate` variable from your controller:

```
<div class="input-append date" id="datepicker" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
    <input size="16" type="text" value="" name="date">
    <input type="submit" style="display:none;" id="submit">
    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
</div>


<%
     date = @defaultdate || Time.now
     date = date.strftime('%Y,%m,%d')
%>


<script>
     var defaultDate = new Date(<%= date %>);
     $("#datepicker").val(defaultDate);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my controller I have:
    `scope :by_date,->(date){ select{|post| post.created_at.to_date == date} }`
My class looks:

```
if signed_in?
      @post = current_user.posts.build
      if(params[:date].blank?)
        @feed_items = current_user.feed.by_date(Time.now.to_date)
      else
        @feed_items = current_user.feed.by_date(params[:date].to_date)
       end
    end
```

I don't know how to make it work perfect.